# I've been to Keflavik, Iceland, but now I can't find it on the map!

Tags: iceland, reykjavik, icelandair

On a whim, I decided to check out Google Maps and see how far it was from Reykjavik to Keflavik (the name of the airport of course, and also, from what I remember, the name of the town for which the airport's named). However, when I search, I can only find a town called Reykjanesbær.

Wikipedia has a listing for the town of Keflavik, and gives [this location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/64%C2%B001'00.0%22N+22%C2%B034'00.0%22W/@64.0111405,-22.5845332,13.07z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d64.016667!4d-22.566667?hl=en). As you can see, it takes me to Reykjanesbær.

What happened?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Google product support, not travel.

Comment: I just happened to use Google Maps as the means of exploring, but the question has nothing to do with it. I am more curious about whether the town has changed its name, or perhaps has been annexed by Reykjanesbær, or similar.

Comment: Do take a second to look at the Wikipedia article: ‘In 1995 **it merged** with Njarðvík and Hafnir **to form a municipality called Reykjanesbær** with a population of 15,233 (January 2016).’

Comment: :) That's the answer. I should have read that. Question answered. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reykjanesb%C3%A6r), Reykjanesbær is a community that encompasses also Njarðvík and Hafnir. The town where your pointer ends up is Keflavik, but the label shown on Google Maps is from the larger community.

If you want a map with the Keflavik label, you can use for example [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=13/63.9921/-22.5635).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't really need a map -- it was more a question of whether they'd changed the name, or if Keflavik had been absorbed by a growing Reykjanesbær.

Comment: Jan answered it in a comment above. The Wikipedia article indicates that it merged with Njarðvík and Hafnir to form a new municipality. Thanks.